# Idiomatic way of naming Getters in Go

Tags: go

The Effective go has following advice on naming of getters:

> Go doesn't provide automatic support for getters and setters. There's
>   nothing wrong with providing getters and setters yourself, and it's
>   often appropriate to do so, but it's neither idiomatic nor necessary
>   to put Get into the getter's name. If you have a field called owner
>   (lower case, unexported), the getter method should be called Owner
>   (upper case, exported), not GetOwner. The use of upper-case names for
>   export provides the hook to discriminate the field from the method. A
>   setter function, if needed, will likely be called SetOwner. Both names
>   read well in practice:

Source: https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#Getters

Now, this advice doesn't seem to consistent as the stdlib itself violates this multiple times. 
[image]

As you can see in above screenshot, there are multiple methods  which use GetX naming convention which is advised against in the effective go guide.

So the question is is the advice given in guide wrong or these methods are named wrongly & would be fixed in future versions?

Comment: My guess is that they named those like the unterlying OS-Methods like in the syscall package and just changed the first letter for export reasons.

Comment: I have never understood this inconsistency in Go. A./ Method names should be verbs. To me it feels wrong to see Owner() as struct getter name. B./ method prefix "get" sets clear semantical contract for the method. It should not do anything else then getting business. To me Owner signals no contract. C./ Again sad inconsistency having Owner() without get prefix and SetOwner with "Set" prefix. Are we doing this to save three characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [[go-nuts] FunctionName caseinconsistencies](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/3FK1G08AfVA/B68aMDIqEOkJ)
>
> A lot of the all lowercase names were chosen before we had really
>   figured out what the naming conventions should be. The rule we
>   adopted, which might be worth revisiting later, was that entry points
>   in package `os` or `syscall`, which are named after equivalents in C, just
>   had a single capital at the beginning, to avoid needing to decide
>   where the internal capitalizations are in abbreviations like `geteuid`
>   or `getwd` or `chdir`.  Names like `Readdirnames`, which are actual words,
>   might be worth revisiting at some point.
>
> Russ

---

> [os: inconsistent casing in names #1187](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/1187)
>
> Is there any sort of rule about the casing of functions used in the
>   "`os`" package?  Looking through, it doesn't sound like it's very easy
>   to recall whether a given function should be called `LikeThat` or
>   `Likethat`.
>
> For instance:
>
> ```
> Mkdir
> MkdirAll
> TempDir
> Getenv
> ForkExec
> Readlink
> ReadAt
> Readdir
> ```
>
> It feels very ad-hoc, and hard to recall.

It's a known issue. It's unplanned.

Answer (score 10):

These names are not consistent with Go naming by design. Rob Pike, one of the Go creators, [says this about the names in the OS package](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/golang-nuts/6joQwydzNyg/discussion):

> There are inconsistencies but this is the key point. It should be Stdout not StdOut, because that name is coming from the underlying system. Similarly it's Fprintf not FPrintf or FPrintF because that is a very familiar name. These names are coming into Go, not being created there, and the initial cap is the admission fee.

The names will not be changed in a future version of Go.

Answer (score 6):

The term "getters" refers to *methods* on *structs* that allow you to read values of (often unexported) *fields* on that struct. The functions you're pointing to are *top-level functions* which allow you to read values *from the OS*.  That idiomatic rule is not relevant to this case.

Comment: No, you are wrong, because those functions also adre name in contrast to the general Naming scheme in go: Mixed Caps. See for example IsExist. See my comment above.

Comment: What part is wrong? What you said is also correct, there's no contradiction.

Comment: Because they even contradict the general Camel-Case Naming Conventions in go. It should be GetPID for example. But you are right about the application of the Getter/Setter rule.

Comment: Sure, camel case naming convention was never part of the question.

Comment: No idea why someone downvoted this answer - it's the first thing I thought of too and completely correct as regards getter method naming (look at the title of this question).